# custom view with parameter from a remote json

Tags: swift, view, uiviewcontroller, init

I have a custom view and the VC for it. The custom view has all kind of things in it, one of these are the labels for the available sizes for the given product. :

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    var productSize: Array<String>
    // all other labels and stuff

    required init(size: Array<String>) {
        self.productSizes = size
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        setupView()
        setupConstraints()
    }
    
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

And the other view:

```
class CustomViewViewController: UIViewController {

    private let productDetailView = ProductDetailsView(size: [])
    let product: Product

}
```

I get the product without any problem, but how should I connect the available sizes with the view? Obviously that empty array there is not correct, how should i connect the data from the remote file with the view init?
I was thinking about making an array and pushing it with the product itself from the original table view like this:

```
if let productsArray = self.productsArray {
    let allSizes: Array<String> = productsArray[indexPath.row].sizes?.components(separatedBy: ",") ?? []
    let customVC = CustomViewViewController(product: productsArray[indexPath.row], allSizes: allSizes)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(customVC, animated: true)
}
```

But I could't really figure out how this one should work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it a `lazy var`

```
lazy var productDetailView:ProductDetailsView = { 
   let res = ProductDetailsView(size:self.product.sizes?.components(separatedBy: ",") ?? [])
   return res
}()
```

**OR**

1-   `var productDetailView:ProductDetailsView!`

2- Inside `viewDidLoad`

```
productDetailView = ProductDetailsView(size:self.product.sizes?.components(separatedBy: ",") ?? [])
```